# How can I get the exact position of bold words in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two cells (let"s say A1 and B1) with same content, but not same formatting (borders, size, background, etc.)

I need to have the same bold words in the two cells.
But I don't want to change any other formattings of A1 and B1

I've made a loop on the text in A1 in order to detect if each letter is in bold or not:

> For i = 1 To Len([A1])
>
> If [A1].Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then [B1].Characters(i,
>   1).Font.Bold = True
>
> Next i

When the length of the text in A1 exceeds 200 letters, this loop takes several seconds to execute, and I need to optimize it.

My idea is to transfer  the "[A1].characters" object in a variable, in order to check faster whether each letter of A1 is in bold or not.

So I create the object [A1].characters:

> set chr=[A1].characters

How can I get the property "bold/not bold" of each letter of the text?

(I'vee been looking for a way to build an array which dimension is the number of letters of A1, with 1's for bold letters and 0's for not bold letters, but I can't find it)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A faster way would be to get the format of cell `B1` you want to keep, copy cell `A1` into `B1`, then apply the original formatting back on `B1`.

Comment: Would it really be faster? keeping copy of all formattings, implies keeping copy of all borders formatting, background formatting, poloce formatting, alignment formatting, etc (Big macro!)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1395042/edit) to give us an example of what you have and what the expected result is. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be useful to help creating a good example.